# Firestore Query not returning

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have two spinners, one with Categories and one with Items that load their info motion from 2 different firestore collections.

I wanted to create a query for the spinner with the items to only show the items corresponding to the category in question

I did this

```
db.collection("List Items").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        for (document in snapshot.documents) {
            val data = document.data
            val subCategories = data["itemName"] as String

            itemSpinnerArray.add(subCategories)


        }

        if (categorySpinnerArray.contains("Weights")) {
            itemSpinnerArray.add(query.toString())

        }

        spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()



    }
```

and the vars are

```
private var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
var weightCategory = db.collection("List Items")
var query = weightCategory.whereEqualTo("categoryId", "0")
```

But it didn't work

Could anyone give me a help please?

This is how my Database is set up

[image: List Items]

[image: Categories]

### EDIT

After creating a Log to see the result, I got this

> 02-08 15:12:30.996 3003-3003/com.reecreate.woderator2 D/TAG: resul in [Barbell, Deadlift Barbell, Climbing Rope, Plyo Box, Bumper Plate, Dumbbell, Kettlebell, Sandbag, 3kg, 5kg, 6kg, Gymnastic Rings]

The category in question that I am trying to pass is weights, therefore as you can see, some items there are not weights. Basically, it is not filtering anything

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Can you show us how is your database structure in firebase ??

Comment: Just updated the post. Check the last two links that have the images of my firestore

Comment: Can you log the result please?

Comment: nothing happens. I am quite sure what I need to do isn't `add` but I don't know what is :/

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the category as a number, but are querying it as a string. That means the values never match. To fix this, pass a number into the query:

```
var query = weightCategory.whereEqualTo("categoryId", 0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Still  not working though

Comment: What isn't working? Please update your question to contain a single, minimal code snippet that shows completely what you've tried. Right now, it is unclear what isn't working, since you're not sharing how you read from the query. Also not what cutiko said in a comment: it's easier to help if you just log/print results, instead of adding them to UI elements that we can't see. See [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints on why this is useful in getting help.

Comment: Isn't the snippet minimal? Can't get smaller than that. As fro the query, I put the variable there on my question. Going to update and show the log

Comment: Look at my side here: I spot a mistake in your query and point it out. You say that doesn't fix "it", so I try to see what else  you're doing with that query. Without seeing that, I can't say what else might be going wrong (although type mismatch I pointed out is definitely a problem).

Comment: yeah yeah you're right, sorry. I should've showed the Log straight away. Can you see it now? :)

Comment: Thanks for the log output. Please also update the code to match, since that's the only way we can know what is being printed. I also don't see how your `addOnSuccessListener` relates to the `query` that you're creating.